# Как правильно закрыть поток? javaFX

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Пишу графический редактор на javaFX.

В главном контроллере отрисовуется окно программы, в фоновом потоке - отрисовуется рисунок. Поток для прорисовки ждет команды и начинает рисовать. после чего заходит на следующих круг и опять ждет команды. Не понимаю как при таком подходе можно закрыть фоновый поток (при закрытии основного окна програмы). Буду благодарен любым советам. Код потока-рисовальщика:

```
public class DrawService implements Runnable{
private GraphicsContext gc;
private Shape shape;

private DrawService() {
}

private DrawService(MainController mc) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    this.isAlive = true;
    this.gc = mc.getCnvs().getGraphicsContext2D();
    this.gcWidth = mc.getCnvs().getWidth();
    this.gcHeight = mc.getCnvs().getHeight();

    thread.start();
}

public static DrawService getInstance(MainController mc){
    if (instance == null){
        synchronized (DrawService.class){
            if (instance == null) instance = new DrawService(mc);
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isAlive) {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            drawShape(shape);

            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                isAlive = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void draw(Shape shape) {
    synchronized (this){
        this.shape = shape;
        notify();
    }
}
```

Я не знаю как мне закрыть этот поток по закрытию основного окна. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Установи у него свойства демона. .setDaemon(true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    System.exit(0);
});
```

При закрытии главного окна программы, завершит все потоки процесса.

Касательно вашего кода, изучите документацию [прерываний](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) и уделите особое внимание `The Interrupt Status Flag`...